# Normalize data for non-negative distribution conditional sampling

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo

Normalizing data is helpful in most MCMC cases. Most of the times the suggested normalization is z-score.
But what happens when I want to normalize data, which then I sample from a non-negative distribution ?

E.g. let's say I model `x = [263.1, 348.4, 362.0, 395.7, 479.2, 974.4]` to come from an Exponential distribution: `x[i] ~ Exponential(λ)`.

Obviously here if we use z-score ($\frac{x-\bar{x}}{\sigma}$), the Exponential sampling will error.

I was thinking something like $\frac{x-min(x)}{\sigma}$, but I am wondering if there is already a suggested way to normalize the `x` vector for such cases ?

Comment: Note that normalization is different from standardization. The former typically consists at converting a variable to have values between zero and one, the latter leads to a variable with mean zero and variance one.

Comment: It should make no difference for the performances of the MCMC sampler.

Comment: @utobi The literature is not consistent on this. I have seen the term normalisation used also for what you call standardisation (even though your use may be in the majority).

Comment: @Xi'an For isolated problems like this one no. But if I want to use the sampled Exponential(λ) to sample another distribution/data and so on, then I believe this could lead to problems.